# Re-hosting a trained model on AWS SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have started exploring AWS SageMaker starting with these [examples provided by AWS](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/blazingtext_word2vec_subwords_text8). I then made some modifications to this particular setup so that it uses the data from my use case for training.

Now, as I continue to work on this model and tuning, after I delete the inference endpoint once, I would like to be able to recreate the same endpoint -- even after stopping and restarting the notebook instance (so the notebook / kernel session is no longer valid) -- using the already trained model artifacts that gets uploaded to S3 under /output folder.

Now I cannot simply jump directly to this line of code:

```
bt_endpoint = bt_model.deploy(initial_instance_count = 1,instance_type = 'ml.m4.xlarge')
```

I did some searching -- including [amazon's own example of hosting pre-trained models](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/blazingtext_hosting_pretrained_fasttext), but I am a little lost. I would appreciate any guidance, examples, or documentation that I could emulate and adapt to my case.

Comment: I am continuing my research and found 3 possible leads --

Comment: ...

(1.) Looks like you can do this from the AWS sagemaker console: Endpoints > Create Endpoint > Use an existing Endpoint Configuration


(2.) Deploy the Model to Amazon SageMaker Hosting Services: https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-sagemaker-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/ex1-deploy-model.md


(3.) SageMaker Python SDK:
https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/session.py


particularly Lines #708 onwards ...


'def endpoint_from_model_data(self, model_s3_location, ...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment is correct - you can re-create an Endpoint given an existing EndpointConfiguration. This can be done via the console, the AWS CLI, or the SageMaker boto client.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-endpoint.html
- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_endpoint