# Can i deploy pretrained sklearn model (pickle in s3) on sagemaker?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I have already developed a scikit learn based machine learning model and have it in a pickle file. I am trying to deploy it only for inferencing and found sagemaker on aws. I do not see scikit learn based libraries on their available libraries and I also do not want to train the model all over again. Is it possible to only deploy the model that is already trained and present in AWS S3 on sagemaker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762367/re-hosting-a-trained-model-on-aws-sagemaker

Comment: it is not a duplicate of what was mentioned above. I have deployed the sklearn model on pickle. Johna's response was helpful

Answer (score 3):

You need to containerize it before deploy to SageMaker.

This might be a good start: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/train-and-host-scikit-learn-models-in-amazon-sagemaker-by-building-a-scikit-docker-container/